# How do I apply removing of characters to the string itself?

Tags: ruby, string, function, pass-by-reference

Using Ruby 2.4.  How do I apply an editing of a stirng to the string itself?  I have this method

```
  # Removes the word from teh end of the string
  def remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, word)
    str[0...(-1 * word.length)]
  end
```

I want the parameter to be operated upon, but it isn't working ...

```
2.4.0 :001 > str = "abc def"
 => "abc def"
2.4.0 :002 > StringHelper.remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, "def")
 => "abc "
2.4.0 :003 > str
 => "abc def"
```

I want the string that was passed in to be equal to "abc " but that isn't happening.  I don't want to set the variable to the result of the function (e.g. "str = StringHelper.remove(...)"

Comment: Maybe put `str = ...` in the method?

Comment: I tried putting "str = str[0...(-1 * word.length)]" as the method body but it doens't change the value of the parameter being passed in.  I didn't include that info b/c I thought ppl would laugh me off this forum for such a suggestion, so it gives me relief that you asked this question.

Comment: Okay if you put `str.replace(str[0...(-1 * word.length)])` in your method that works. Not sure if it's the best way to go about things though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby already has the `String#delete!` method that does exactly this:

```
>> str = 'abc def'
=> "abc def"
>> word = 'def'
=> "def"
>> str.delete!(word)
=> "abc "
>> str
=> "abc "
```

Note that this will remove all instances of `word`:

```
>> str = 'def abc def'
=> "def abc def"
>> str.delete!(word)
=> " abc "
```

To limit the effect to only the last word, you can do:

```
>> str = 'def abc def'
=> "def abc def"
>> str.slice!(-word.length..-1)
=> "def"
>> str
=> "def abc "
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  If the string is "abc def def", your function returns "abc " but I only want to remove the last word, and so in such a case I would want "abc def ".

Comment: @Natalia I added an option that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`str[range]` is just a shorthand for `str.slice(range)`. You just have to use the destructive method, like that :

```
# Removes the word from the end of the string
def remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, word)
    str.slice!((str.length - word.length)...(str.length))
end
```

For more information, see [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-slice).

If you want your function to return the new string as well, you should use :

```
# Removes the word from the end of the string
def remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, word)
    str.slice!((str.length - word.length)...(str.length))
    str
end
```

Comment: THis doesn't work.  If my str = "Aurora CO" and I invoke your function where word = "CO", the result of str after calling teh function is "CO".  I woudl expect it to be "Aurora ".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, word)
    str.slice!((str.length - word.length)..str.length)
end
```

Also, your explanation is a little confusing. You are calling the remove_word method as a class method but it is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

`chomp!` returns a the String with the given record separator removed from the end of string (if present), and `nil` if nothing was removed.

```
def remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, word)
  str.chomp!( "CO")
end

str = "Aurora CO" 
remove_word_from_end_of_str(str, "CO")
p str  #=> "Aurora "
```